# OS X: prevent close window [X] button from deleting open tabs in any application

Tags: macos

Nowadays many programs heavily rely on tabs - from browsers, to text editors, IDEs, filesystem browsers, email tools, etc. Many of these work like this: when the application is closed it remembers its state, i.e. the last opened tabs, and on restarting it the tabs will be loaded.

### The problem

- On Mac OS X the red `X` button on the top left only closes the current window not the application.
- In many cases this leads to all tabs being lost. Examples: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Sublime Text, ...

**Is there *any* way we can prevent the red `X` from deleting the open tabs in the application in question?**

What I tried so far:

- There is a small tool called RedQuits, which will *close* applications after you hit the red `X`. Sadly this seems to happen after the window close, i.e. the restarted application will still have lost all tabs.
- Just never touching the red `X`. Well, this hasn't worked out so well for me... I lose all my browser tabs and text editor tabs on a regular basis. Very annoying.
- Just using `Cmd+Q` to quit programs. Sure, this works 98% of the time. But the red `X` remains as an annoying little land mine.

To be honest, I would even be happy just to disable the red `X` all together for all applications. Right now in many of the tools I work with daily the `X` button is just a trap which must *never* be touched.

--> It'd be nice to have a UI which doesn't feel like playing Mine Sweeper, where one wrong click at any point in time will cost me a lot of time getting my work history back.

Comment: I sympathise with your plight. I have a few choice words to say when I click the red x in Windows & the damn thing closes the app. It's a paradigm difference, you just have to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been doing a bit of digging on the apple forums and how to remove it by using terminal or something. It looks like you can't, I think it's just the way software is designed. :(

Comment: I get that the OS X behaviour is different than the one on Windows/Linux/... But with the current reliance on tabbed programs this feature is becoming a burden.